# Can I play a sound effect when I click a button?

Tags: interface, audio

Can I hear a sound as feedback when I click a button in the UI or click the mouse?

I think that if I hear sounds in blender when I operate, I can enjoy more work.

Answer (score 1):

There is no facility for this. Of course you can do it, but it would require you to edit Blender's C code and write it yourself.